# Sum count different in scala and SQL

Tags: scala, hive

Scala sum and SQL query sum giving different count. The sum for SQL query is showing very high has compared to scala query output. Any reason why it will be different

```
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df = spark.sql( "select * from view_error_log")
val grpdf = df.groupby("id","error_description","table", "log_date").agg(sum("totalRows").alias("totalRows"))

%sql
Select id,error_description,table,log_date,sum(totalRows) as TotalRows from
view_error_log group by id,error_description,table,log_date
```

Comment: Should there be a group by clause in the SQL query? It looks incomplete.

Comment: It has the group by clause   %sql
Select id,error_description,table,log_date,sum(totalRows) as TotalRows from
view_error_log group by id,error_description,table,log_date

Comment: Oops, I apologize, I missed it.